# Does having multiple loops in python increase the script efficiency?

Tags: python, multithreading

I am very new to python, and I was making a brute force password cracker game where the user enters a password, and the program would generate random numbers and try to crack the user input. I used random.randint() to generate the numbers. The program works great at small numbers (under 7 digits) but the time required to guess the number increases exponentially as the user inputs increase in digits. A six-digit number would approximately take at least a second to crack, while a seven-digit number costs about 30 seconds to crack. In an attempt to upgrade the performance of the code, I used multiple threadings. Code down here:

```
# password is user input
max_num = pow(10, len(password))
min_num = pow(10, len(password)-1)
def r():
    global max_num, min_num
    start = time.time()
    while True:
        guess = random.randint(min_num,max_num)
        if guess == int(password):
            print('Your password is: ' + ''.join(str(guess)))
            end = time.time()
            print('Random time: '+str(end-start))
            break
b = lambda :r()
threading.Thread(target=b).start()
threading.Thread(target=b).start()
threading.Thread(target=b).start()
threading.Thread(target=b).start()
threading.Thread(target=b).start()
```

It may sound silly, but would the code crack the password faster if I thread 5 of the function simultaneously?

Answer (score 1):

Python has a Global Interpreter Lock (GIL), which prevents threads from being executed concurrently. Therefore, you won't gain any speed from using Threads. Instead, if you want to achieve parallelism, use the multiprocessing module.

Also, I would not recommend using random numbers to crack the password, it is better to explore all the combinations in order (or with any other method that does not repeat passwords and ensures all possibilities are explored)

Comment: Thank you, I have coded the method using for loops!

Answer (score 0):

Python threads are limited by the [Global Interpreter Lock (GIL)](https://wiki.python.org/moin/GlobalInterpreterLock), meaning that more threads does not equal more speed in Python. You can get around this by multiprocessing, which spawns a separate Python interpreter in its own memory space for each process.

The [multiprocessing library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html) in Python should have what you need. For this task specifically, you would be best served by a [ProcessPoolExecutor](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#processpoolexecutor-example).